# how to find ISO label

Tags: iso

I want to see the iso label info of an iso, for using in the kickstart,

how to see the iso label in windows as well as in linux?

example: am trying to find a iso image label for CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso

use this label in the kickstart file in inst.stage2

Comment: [Crossposted](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4074/31256 "Crossposting Etiquette") a few hours ealier on [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1532130/218574 "How to see a iso label on windows and linux")...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `isoinfo` from the `genisoimage` package and extract the "Volume id":

```
isoinfo -d -i CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso | sed -n 's/Volume id: //p'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can lable ISO image, but you can use this command to get all labels for all drives on your machine `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label`